# VS2008 automatically signing me in under windows credentials to TFS Cloud. How to use different credentials?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have searched all over the interwebs in an attempt to solve this issue.

VS2012 has the signout link that allows you to switch creds when connecting to different tfs servers.  I am using VS2008 for some older projects and it passes through the login creds to the tfs server connection, but has no built in capabilities to signout of these creds.

I have tried deleting IE cookies, removing credentials from User Accts from within the control panel, and numerous other postings out on the web.  None of which have worked.

I get the standard error. :

tf31002  Unable to connect to TFS server.

I have also seen the posts on stackoverflow regarding this but none of the solutions have worked for me.

Any ideas on a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up deleting IE cookies, restarting vs2008, and then connecting to my tfs service url location.  I think part of the problem was that initially I wasn't specifying the default collection in the url.  Someone wiped out this previous setting so I hadn't entered this in a while.